# Run-time error '13' VBA code highlighting last data point

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, type-mismatch

I found this macro and tried to adjust it to run on every chart. It is supposed to highlight the final point of data for every graph and highlight only series 1.
I get an error:

> Run-time error '13': Type Mismatch

on line `Set cht = ws.ChartObjects`

```
    Sub LastPointLabel()
      Dim srs As Series
      Dim iPts As Long
      Dim cht As Chart
      Dim ws As Worksheet
      Dim bLabeled As Boolean
      Set ws = ActiveSheet

      Set cht = ws.ChartObjects
    Set srs = cht.SeriesCollection(1)
  For Each cht In sht.ChartObjects
          bLabeled = False
          With srs
            For iPts = .Points.Count To 1 Step -1
              If bLabeled Then
                ' handle error if point isn't plotted
                On Error Resume Next
                ' remove existing label if it's not the last point
                srs.Points(iPts).HasDataLabel = False
                On Error GoTo 0
              Else
                ' handle error if point isn't plotted
                On Error Resume Next
                ' add label
                srs.Points(iPts).ApplyDataLabels _
                    ShowSeriesName:=True, _
                    ShowCategoryName:=False, ShowValue:=False, _
                    AutoText:=True, LegendKey:=False
                bLabeled = (Err.Number = 0)
                On Error GoTo 0
              End If
            Next
          End With
        Next

    End Sub
```

Comment: cht is declared as a single Chart. But it is set to a collection of ChartObjects

Comment: @JeremyKahan changed to ```Dim cht As ChartObject``` but still get the same error

Comment: That makes sense, because ChartObjects is an array of ChartObject

Comment: @JeremyKahan still getting the same error though

Comment: No, I mean the error makes sense. If you Dim cht As ChartObject, you cannot set this single ChartObject to the array of ChartObject given by ChartObjects

Comment: I don't think you need Set cht = ws.ChartObjects, and I think you want that Set srs as the first line inside the for loop (not before)

Comment: Ahh yes. I also had to adjust it to ```Set srs = cht.Chart.SeriesCollection(1)```

Answer (score 1):

Had to adjust:

`Dim cht as Chart`

**to**

`Dim cht as ChartObject`

and adjusted and moved

`Set srs = cht.SeriesCollection(1)`

**to**

`Set srs = cht.Chart.SeriesCollection(1)`

below the loop start

also removed line `Set cht = ws.ChartObjects` from the code

Thanks to @JeremyKahan